# Retrieve Lotus Designer information from java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-designer

Is there a way to from an external java program get information which is normally available in Lotus Designer?

I am able to get Form Names, Field Names and Field Types and do similarly for Views using Notes.jar but I am unable to pull other information such as Combobox Choices or data about Pages, Code, Navigators etc.

Does anybody know if there is an existing utility (besides obviously designer) which is capable of pulling this information, or whether there is a jar file besides Notes.jar which is capable of pulling this information.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXPORTING_AND_IMPORTING_DXL_JAVA.html

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you. that link has helped me get a lot of the information that I am looking for.

Comment: Great! Feel free to expand on the solution and post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options you can consider. All of them involve the inclusion of IBM provided JARs.

- You can get hand on the design elements as objects using Java methods as defined in the Notes Java API. Design elements are documents, so you can process them. Most of the time that's not too helpful.
- Access the Design elements as DXL, which is a relative accurate representation of Domino objects in XML. On OpenNTF there is a project I wrote named DXLMagic that does DXL exports, you might want to look at the source
- Domino designer has support for version control. When you set it up, Domino Designer copies the design content of an NSF into a directory structure. You can process that directory (containing DXL, XML, PlainText and resource files) with any tool you fancy
- To access an NSF in Domino Designer the Eclipse Virtual File System API has been used (instead of File it uses the IResource interface). When you "borrow" the EVFS plug-in you could use it in any OSGI application.

Hope that helps